# Flutter Application : Location fetch in background

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, background-process, live-tracking

I want to keep my application running or a piece of code which can perform some operation like getting a current location and call an API to submit that  location.

I saw the background_fetch plugin but it says, app can not fetch the callback before 15 minutes in background so it is not feasible solution for tracking a location to get location every 15 minutes, so is there any way that can make possible to keep running some code in background.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: Though, I have implemented my own location service in native using platform channels. But now there are some plugins available. Check out this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/background_location.

Answer (score 2):

In flutter, code can be executed in background using **Isolates**

Isolates are Dart’s model for multithreading, though an isolate differs from a conventional thread in that it doesn’t share a memory with the main program.

Check [this](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) post for more info.

Comment: Sure, I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: is there any restriction for android like we can just run call backs every 15 minutes as the background_fetch plugin says? Your answer seems correct but if there is restrictions like that then it does not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Now officially there is some plugins for background location tracking. check out below links:

1. [background_Locations](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locations)
2. [background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location)

Comment: This does not worked for me because it was crashing my application so probably it is in development so it might be buggy.so i just submitted an issue for that plugin